# Container with a fullscreen background image in Yii2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2-advanced-app

I'm trying to get full screen background image for this container:

```
<div class="header"

    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <h2 class="text-center">test1</h2>

                <p class="lead text-center">test2</p>

                <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success"
                                          href="http://localhost/"><span
                            class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> something</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But, the picture is showing without fullscreen view and i'm trying to get something like this:

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-business-frontpage/

**and i followed every tutorial for it, but nothing is worked.!**

i'm not sure if i'm using `Yii2` with this `bootstrap`makes any sense.

**Btw, this is my site.css**

```
html,
.my-navbar {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    background: #F5F5F5;
}

.footer {
    height: 180px;
    background-color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.wrap {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto -60px;
    padding: 0 0 60px;
}

.wrap > .container {
    padding: 70px 15px 20px;
}

.header {
    height: 400px;
    background: url('../images/header.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    min-height:100%;
    background-size:100px 150px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron .btn {
    font-size: 21px;
    padding: 14px 24px;
}

.not-set {
    color: #c55;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* add sorting icons to gridview sort links */
a.asc:after, a.desc:after {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings', fantasy;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

a.asc:after {
    content: /*"\e113"*/ "\e151";
}

a.desc:after {
    content: /*"\e114"*/ "\e152";
}

.sort-numerical a.asc:after {
    content: "\e153";
}

.sort-numerical a.desc:after {
    content: "\e154";
}

.sort-ordinal a.asc:after {
    content: "\e155";
}

.sort-ordinal a.desc:after {
    content: "\e156";
}

.grid-view th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.hint-block {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #999;
}

.error-summary {
    color: #a94442;
    background: #fdf7f7;
    border-left: 3px solid #eed3d7;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}
```

What should i do for achieve full screen background image like this example in header?

http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-business-frontpage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the header css

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

It should work now.

Comment: thanks a lot, it's working but the only problem is the body content is being wrapped at header, see:http://i.imgur.com/XOUvEG9.png

Comment: Add **margin-top: 450px;** to the content you want under the header. That should help

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to putt it up as an example on Codepen?

Your div class "header" doesn't have an ending ">" which might be causing some problems.

Try with the following in the CSS where the background img is specified:

```
  background-size:cover;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a other class with container class and use background image with cover option. Here i use .bimg for example.

`<div class="container bimg"></div>`

```
.bimg{
    width:100%;
    background:url('PATH');
}
```